# Unable to create databases java.sql.SQLException: Could not find declared field with name ... for class

Tags: java, android, ormlite

Hy!

I'm using android studio and working on an android project. I tried to create a database with around 57 table. I have the following error message:

> Unable to create datbases java.sql.SQLException: Could not find
>   declared field with name 'warehouseOverstore' for class
>   com.icecube.iceman.model.dto.AddressEntity
>
> In addressEntity hasn't got any field called warehouseOverstore. Never
>   was declared too. In ormlite_config doesn't containing any references
>   to warehouseOverstore.

If i leave out that createTable instruction, the app run without any error. What's the problem?

*ormlite_config* extract:

```
# --table-start--
dataClass=com.icecube.iceman.model.dto.AddressEntity
tableName=address
# --table-fields-start--
fieldName=id
columnName=_id
generatedId=true
fieldName=name
columnName=name
fieldName=zip
columnName=zip
fieldName=country
columnName=country
fieldName=city
columnName=city
fieldName=district
columnName=district
fieldName=street
columnName=street
fieldName=streetnumber
columnName=streetNumber
fieldName=block
columnName=block
fieldName=building
columnName=building
fieldName=type
columnName=type
# --table-fields-end--
# --table-end--
```

AddressEntity:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName="address" )
public class AddressEntity implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// ENTITY PRIMARY KEY ( BASED ON A SINGLE FIELD )
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@DatabaseField(generatedId = true, columnName = "_id")
private Integer    id           ;


//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// ENTITY DATA FIELDS 
//----------------------------------------------------------------------
@DatabaseField(columnName="name")
private String     name         ;

@DatabaseField(columnName="zip", canBeNull=false)
private String     zip          ;

@DatabaseField(columnName="country", canBeNull=false)
private String     country      ;

@DatabaseField(columnName="city", canBeNull=false)
private String     city         ;

@DatabaseField(columnName="district")
private String     district     ;

@DatabaseField(columnName="street")
private String     street       ;

@DatabaseField(columnName="streetNumber")
private String     streetnumber ;

@DatabaseField(columnName="block")
private String     block        ;

@DatabaseField(columnName="building")
private String     building     ;

@DatabaseField(columnName="type", canBeNull=false)
private String     type         ;

// After that just constructor and getter/setters. No reference on warehauseOverstore
```

Thank You for your helps.

Comment: Please attach you model class..

Comment: done it (modified question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DaoManager.clearCache(); command solved it. Placed it in that class constructor, which extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper

Answer (score 0):

Are you creating this project from scratch or you are trying to modify existing project?
If it's a new project why you are using OrmLite? Google created Room recently and I really recommend you to use it ;). I used OrmLite too, but it generates long cold start, so I decided to leave it.

If you really need an OrmLite, do you have variable called `warehouseOverstore` anywhere in your project?

Comment: I'm modifying and axisting project. Got warehauseOverstore variable in other class, but not in Address. And its an Entity like Address.

Answer (score 0):

You need to regenerate `ormlite_config` file by **running** `OrmLiteConfigUtil.java`

[image]